# Pass value of cell via href from JSP to controller

Tags: jquery, jsp, tags

I need to pass the value of a cell to controller using href tag. In this case value is populated from database. Is this the best way to do it?   Im not sure how its done I have tried but its not working. Do I need java script as well? HELP!

```
<td class="ln" <a href="AnalysisController"><c:out value="${summary.labelNbr}" /></a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td class="ln"><a href="AnalysisController?value=${summary.labelNbr}"><c:out value="${summary.labelNbr}" /></a></td>
```